# Listing large 1000 shared drives from Google drive via API

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to get all shared drive, large 1000 shared drive via API or export it to a list

only get 1000 shared drive via admin and API

In google document about shared drive, they limit view 1000 shared drive,
`Drive lists up to 1,000 shared drives in the left navigation. You can still access the other shared drives using the direct URL, or search for specific files and folders in the shared drives.`
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/7338880?hl=en

I using api but still can not load over 1000 shared drive
[https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A100%2C%22pageToken%22%3A%22~!!~AI9FV7RNwVtQIVYh3GH4Dm6wzTfzUsZ4TbO_2SItIN1lJ7CvzZR7vmzZfZIQCEqS6eHx2Xc8lsAb%22%2C%22useDomainAdminAccess%22%3Atrue%7D#try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A100%2C%22pageToken%22%3A%22%7E!!%7EAI9FV7RNwVtQIVYh3GH4Dm6wzTfzUsZ4TbO_2SItIN1lJ7CvzZR7vmzZfZIQCEqS6eHx2Xc8lsAb%22%2C%22useDomainAdminAccess%22%3Atrue%7D#try-it)

How to list all >1000 shared drive via API, or export to a list?

Thank you

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I using api but still can not load over 1000 shared drive`? You have already been able to retrieve a list of 1000 shared drives using `pageToken`. But, you cannot retrieve the shared drive of more than 1000. Is my understanding correct? And, in your situation, what language do you want to achieve your goal using?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your discussion, I had using pageToken, it must because limit 100 perpage, I had using PHP and load all item with pageToken, and total have 1000 item https://imgur.com/a/TX2tUpw .  Many item hidden, but can found if using q param.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your provided image. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, how about adding your current script to your question? By this, I think that it will help users think of your current issue.

Comment: @Tanaike here is my code https://github.com/vulieumang/shared-drive-api

Comment: @Tanaike Really thank you for your helping, I really need find a way. Here is my way, I get clientId, clientSecret and get auth. then load all shared drive with API drive https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?pageSize=100, and using for loop with pageToken to load end page, and I load <1000 share drive. Missing some drive, I still find that drive if using param "q" for search link here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-shareddrives

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your script retrieves the metadata of 100 shared drives using `pageToken` with PHP script. And, you have more than 1000 shared drives. But, only 1000 shared drives are retrieved. If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. So, in this case, I would like to recommend asking the Google side and reporting it to Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: As another direction, from `Missing some drive, I still find that drive if using param "q" for search link here`, as a workaround, for example, by supposing that the current specification retrieves only 1000 items, how about retrieving the shared drive list using the search query? For example, if your shared drive name has specific names, how about retrieving the part of the drive name by multiple requests? But, I'm not sure whether this is the best way. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have some drive i remember name and i using search name, and it found, but list in api not found, search is only find some drive, not list all, but we can find shared drive, which not show in account and api

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about your whole shared drives, I apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: I think you can help, can you give me more patience. My drive have more 1000 shared drive, and more drive was hidden and can not find it in drive account, and I think can using api, but api still can list all.

Comment: have a way to found some shared drive if we remember name, using api and find name, we can show id shared drive. But we can not remember all drive name :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250203/discussion-between-dinh-tin-v-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I apologize for my poor skill. In your situation, are there patterns in your shared drive name? I thought that the pattern might be able to be used for retrieving all shared drives. By the way, in your situation, how many shared drives do you have?

Comment: yes, have a pattern name is: id - group - fullname, ex: 135 - 20 - Jack Sparrow. Have about 1500, because last id is 1580. How we can retrieving all shared drives? do you have any idea?

Comment: Thank you, with your help, I have more believe to find way, may without you I had give up :)

Answer (score 0):

Happy to show my friends, I found the way to do that.

1. we need account admin, the account can access to this link
   [image: https://admin.google.com/ac/drive/manageshareddrives?]
2. we need add param useDomainAdminAccess=true

Easy we can test easy before coding in Google playground
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list#try-it

[image: we need account supper admin and add useDomainAdminAccess=true]

And here is my result I can load 1699 shared drive
[image]

Thank you for my friends K, M, and Tanaike, I am happy to see you.